# Sorting in two different ways. But getting the wrong Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures, list-comprehension

below given are the two different ways of checking if a list is sorted.

**Method 1**

```
for i in range(len(inord) - 2):
    if (inord[i] >= inord[i + 1]):
        return False
return True
```

**Method 2**

```
temp = sorted(inord)
return min([1 if i==j else 0 for i,j in zip(temp,inord)])
```

The two methods are the same, But the second method fails in some cases, How could that just happen?.

*The above question was asked with reference to the question from HackerRank. Check the below link for the complete code:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/is-binary-search-tree/forum/comments/522743*

Comment: Whet you say it "fails" you mean...?

Comment: The -2 seems incorrect.

Comment: @kindall It doesn't sort the array

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. The range in your first line doesn't compare the last two elements. It should be `-1` instead of `-2`.
2. The first code block returns `False` if two adjacent elements are the same. In the other method, sorting doesn't change the order of same elements, so it returns `True` in the end. Do you want to check for monotonically increasing or strictly monotonically increasing values?

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, Actually I understood your first explanation, but I didn't get your 2. explanation.

Comment: Try the input `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4]`. The first algorithm will return `False` because `2 >= 2` (when `i` is `1`). The second algorithm sorts the list which returns the same values and therefore returns `True` in the end. If the input list is sorted but contains a value multiple times (2 in this case), The two algorithms will return different values. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Perfect. I got them. Thank you so much

Comment: Would you mind voting and accepting this answer? That's for other people to see that the question has been answered (and gives a reward for me as the one who answered the question). Thanks in advance!